# Having trouble with retina output of a fabricjs toDataURL call against the canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm using the most recent fabric.js dist library ([December 24th](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/commits/master/dist/fabric.js)), and having trouble with canvas output for retina.

Here is a JS Fiddle that shows the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/eucht4sd/8/

When the browser has a `devicePixelRatio` of 1, the outputted image is:
[image]

However when the ratio is `2`, the outputted image is: [image]

My understanding is fabric.js takes care of the scaling by detecting the ratio. Am I doing something wrong, or is there any issue with how the canvas is exported when it's a retina monitor?

Comment: This is something to be improved as already discussed here: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/2744 you will get retina enanched image as soon as we fix it. Soon!

Comment: Thanks @AndreaBogazzi Any possible timeline? Don't want to revert back to previous version as it would break a bunch of toher things :(

Comment: i will try to push it today, it should be simple, if i cannot push it soon you can still check the code on our github and put in by yourself.

Comment: Okay let me know on here when it's pushed and I'll mark this question as answered. Thanks @AndreaBogazzi